# Chrome extension HTML5 video fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a dummy HTML5 video tag inside the popup.html of a chrome extension - I notice the full screen control does nothing while inside of the popup -  Is there anyway to make the video go fullscreen, or perhaps just make the video fill the popup?

Comment: What kind of video tag you're using? Is it an embedded iframe Youtube video?

Comment: @jess No it's simply a HTML5 video tag, see this for an example (http://camendesign.co.uk/code/video_for_everybody/test.html). It does not seem to matter what source I use (embedded youtube etc), fullscreen is simply rejected.

Interestingly the equivalent MS Edge extension fills  the popup window when the fullscreen control is clicked

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to get the window full screen using an HTML5 video tag. But using embedded iframe Youtube video, there's a way.